# Android Jetpack Compose CircularProgressIndicator Set Min and Max Progress

Tags: android, kotlin, progress, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to set min and max progress of `CircularProgressIndicator` But I couldn't found any solution.

This is the given **Composable CircularProgressIndicator**:

```
@Composable
fun CircularProgressIndicator(
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    progress: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth
) {
    val stroke = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Butt)
    }
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics(progress)
            .size(CircularIndicatorDiameter)
            .focusable()
    ) {
        // Start at 12 O'clock
        val startAngle = 270f
        val sweep = progress * 360f
        drawDeterminateCircularIndicator(startAngle, sweep, color, stroke)
    }
}
```

It only accepts progress in the range of float which **0.0 to 1.0** I want to change this to accept value from 0 to 100.

**Note:**

I also found out this `Modifier.progressSemantics` But I don't know how to use it to change the progress range.

```
@Stable
fun Modifier.progressSemantics(
    value: Float,
    valueRange: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float> = 0f..1f,
    /*@IntRange(from = 0)*/
    steps: Int = 0
): Modifier {
    val progress = (
        if (valueRange.endInclusive - valueRange.start == 0f) 0f
        else (value - valueRange.start) / (valueRange.endInclusive - valueRange.start)
        ).coerceIn(0f, 1f)

    // We only display 0% or 100% when it is exactly 0% or 100%.
    val percent = when (progress) {
        0f -> 0
        1f -> 100
        else -> (progress * 100).roundToInt().coerceIn(1, 99)
    }

    return semantics {
        stateDescription = "$percent percent"
        progressBarRangeInfo =
            ProgressBarRangeInfo(value.coerceIn(valueRange), valueRange, steps)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The progressIndicator hasn't a label. Using a range 0.0-1.0 or 0-100 is the same.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sir, sorry but I didn't get it. 1st ```CircularProgressIndicator``` takes only progress in Float, 2nd if I give greater value than **1.0** in ```progress``` it will fill the whole progress bar which I don't want.

Comment: What is the problem to turn 0-100 into 0.0-1.0? Just divide by 100 your value.

Comment: I am using ```CountDownTimer``` class with **1min = 60000 milis**  with **1000** interval on every **onTick** I received 60000 - 1000. For eg: on First Tick I recived = 59000 milis I convert it ```59000 / 1000 = 59``` then ```59 / 100 = 0.59```  then set in progress which will fill the whole progress on 1st Tick.

Comment: No. In your case you have to divide the value for 60000. 1000/60000 = 0,016 for each tick

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks a lot Sir, For your time. I really appreciated your help. given your last comment, I did ```val progress = givenValueOnTick.toFloat / 60000``` which start the progress from the end to start but it's still acceptable. Jetpack Compose is hard for me :(   **You can Answer it I will accept it** Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to reverse the progress use: `1 - (givenValueOnTick.toFloat / 60000)`. Just answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need to change the progress range.
Just turn your range into **0.0 - 1.0**.

Just divide the progress value by 60000.
`1000/60000 = 0.016` for each tick.

If you want to reverse the count just use something like:
`val progress = 1 - (givenValueOnTick.toFloat / 60000)`